# Removing background auto fill color from inputSelect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield

So I have a ui:inputSelect tag and when I use auto fill, the background color changes to yellow. How do I get rid of this feature and just keep the white background.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a form?

Comment: no. It is in my lightning component .cmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply some custom css to remove this. I have one for iinputText you can add it your UI tag.

```
/* Change the white to any color ;) */
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset;
}
```

Additionally, you can use this to change the text color:

```
/*Change text in autofill textbox*/
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
}
```

As this is related to browser and not with lightning.